# How to call `setViewControllers: animated:` in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I try to alter my view controller within navigation controller when an user taps a button, so I declared the following code:

```
if standingsViewController == nil {
   standingsViewController = StandingsViewController()
   splitViewController!.delegate = standingsViewController
}
var vc = splitViewController!.viewControllers[1] as UINavigationController
vc.setViewControllers([standingsViewController], animated: true)
```

However, this causes an error: `fatal error: attempt to bridge an implicitly unwrapped optional containing nil` on the last line.

`UINavigationController`'s `setViewControllers: animated:` method is defined in Swift properly, so how can I fix up the problem?

For your information when I try to change it to `[standingsViewController]!`, it didn't even pass the compiling because `[AnyObject] is not identical to [AnyObject]!`.

I use Xcode 6.1 beta in Swift.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to unwrap:

```
vc.setViewControllers([standingsViewController!], animated: true)
```

instead of

```
vc.setViewControllers([standingsViewController], animated: true)
```

Comment: Can you check if `standingsViewController` is nil before `setViewControllers` call? It looks like it is.

Comment: Ah, it was `nil`. It looks like it's because I defined the `weak var standingsViewController: StandingsViewController!` in the top of the class instead of just `var`. I appreciate it.